# Dspace integration with OAI-PMH

Tags: dspace, oai

I'm developing a MVC C# application where I've requested data from an external institution's website. They have informed me that the data will be provided by OAI-PMH.

So on exploring i came across Dspace tool. My question is how searching is done using Dspace? Whether the search query parameters(like title,author etc) are send to the OAI and matched records are taken or whole XML returned from OAI-PMH is taken and put in a RDBMS and search is done?
Please correct if i am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

DSpace is a repository system.  A DSpace instance can be an OAI provider and/or an OAI consumer.  Searching in DSpace is performed in the repository using SQL and SOLR.

The DSpace project provides a sample OAI service at http://demo.dspace.org/oai/request?verb=Identify which you could explore.